# Does QueryDSL supports Hibernate 5.2?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

I am working on setting up POC project with Springboot 1.4.1, Spring-data-jpa, Hibernate 5.2 and QueryDSL 4.1.4 frameworks. When I use the queryDSL I am getting the results but the connections are not getting released. When I use Spring Data or JPQL or JDBCTemplate no issues with connections.

I have looked into QueryDSL samples it is using Hibernate 4.3.11. 
Does anyone used above frameworks combination? 
I really appreciate sample project or some pointers?

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: The problem was how I was injecting entityManager.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I was injecting entityManager.

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL doesn't support Hibernate 5.2 yet

[See this issue on Github](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/1917)

Hopefully though it'll be there soon since Spring Boot 2.0.0+ only supports Hibernate 5.2 and above